# django -newsletter subscription

Tags: django, newsletter

as a newbie to python and django i set up a test project.
I added the django-newsletter-subscription but i can't see it in the frontend.I am able to edit in the admin.
I created an app named newsletters,added one extra field.
In my newsletters file the urls.py looks like that.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from newsletters.models import Subscription
from newsletter_subscription.backend import ModelBackend
from newsletter_subscription.urls import newsletter_subscriptions_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^newsletter/', include(newsletter_subscriptions_urlpatterns(
        backend=ModelBackend(Subscription),))
    ),
)
```

And in my projects file urls.py like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    # Examples:                   
    url(r'^$', 'hospital.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^intro/', include('intro.urls')),
    url(r'^newsletter/', include('newsletter.urls')),                   
)
```

Any help?
Couldn't find a solution somehow.
Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In django-newsletter-subscription the URLconf entry is something like this.

```
from .newsletter.models import Subscription
```

In your code

```
from newsletters.models import Subscription
```

Comment: chandu i tried your solution,it doesnt seem to work.Notice that i named my app newsletters.Now comes with this «No module named newsletter.models».Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked by adding that . infront of the newsletters?

Comment: Yes i did, nothing happens.I can't solve it,strange!

Comment: By adding it can't display the home page.Deleting it home page appears.Something wrong with the urls maybe?

Comment: from django.db import models
from newsletter_subscription.models import SubscriptionBase

class Subscription(SubscriptionBase):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.full_name

Comment: Just like i wrote before «No module named newsletter.models».

Comment: check where you added newsletter.models in the code,because your project name is newsletters not newsletter.

Comment: I installed django newsletter subscription via pip.Created an app called newsletters and over there i put the code i saw you before.

Comment: @Harrk could you add the model code that you have posted in one of the previous comments into the original question? Below the tags *django* and *newsletter* there are these tiny links, one of which is `edit`. It helps a lot in terms of readability. (-:

Comment: Here you are.from django.db import models
from newsletter_subscription.models import SubscriptionBase

class Subscription(SubscriptionBase):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.full_name